# Item List without line alignment. GridView, ListView, Just Views or anything else?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to create such a list? (Look at the picture, 2nd case "???")
Thanks.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager**

```
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

for more information follow this link [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

[image]

Comment: That's what I need! Thank you !